# Double-click highlight selection in Pharo 5.0

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

In older versions of Pharo when you double-click a class name or any word in a text container, it it highlighted. However in Pharo 5, under Windows, this does not work anymore.

Is there any way to revert to older behavior?

Smalltalk vm version. 'CoInterpreter VMMaker.oscog-eem.1855 uuid: d8e4a3c2-a3bf-4adc-b224-8012903a1ef4 May  4 2016
StackToRegisterMappingCogit VMMaker.oscog-eem.1855 uuid: d8e4a3c2-a3bf-4adc-b224-8012903a1ef4 May  4 2016
https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo-vm.git Commit: b8ec25a570d7539653e1d793e97609adb509aaed Date: 2016-05-04 11:14:22 +0200 By: Esteban Lorenzano  Jenkins build #589
'

Comment: I'm not having this problem in Pharo 5.0. Can you cite a specific example (including what Window you're in - *e.g.*, Playground)?

Comment: It happens in all windows where text can be selected

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't happen on my system. Any Window in which text can be selected a double click will select it..

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I cannot reproduce the behaviour you are reporting.

I can double-click on a word and word clicked is properly selected (tested under win XP and win 10)...

- how did you downloaded it?
- is that a "clean" image?
- Which vm version are you using? (`Smalltalk vm version` will answer that)
- Can you try zeroconf? (`wget -O- get.pharo.org | bash && ./pharo-ui Pharo.image`)

Comment: I also have this problem on Window 7. It happened to me many times but not on fresh images. I don't know how to reproduce it, that's why I did not opened an issue yet :(
I use Pharo 5 - 6 from the Pharo launcher

Comment: I added the vm version info. I downloaded using zeroconf, I discovered it happens after I load some packages, it could be a key combination which disables word selection.

Comment: I opened an issue: https://pharo.fogbugz.com/f/cases/18859/Loading-a-package-break-word-selection-on-Windows

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in Windows 10 with Pharo 6.1 (and remember also having it with Pharo 5). Digging around with Google I found that this number is hard-coded to 350ms in the `HandMorph` class `initialize` method:

```
initialize
    "HandMorph initialize"

    PasteBuffer := nil.
    DoubleClickTime := 350.
    NormalCursor := CursorWithMask normal asCursorForm.
```

In a Playground, I entered:

```
HandMorph doubleClickTime: 500
```

and this seems to help.